# Display Loading gif while getting datas

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I would like to display a loading gif in WPF while I'm getting datas in database and querying theses.
I Have a MainWindow with 2 usercontrols and my image/loading gif.

I suppose I must use BackgroundWork but I don't manage to make it works.

Thank you.

Comment: what you want is called a `Splash Screen` do a google search on how to create one as well as use BackgroundWorker in WPF application I am sure that there are tons of examples on how to do this

Comment: A Splash Screen isn,T only at the opening of the solution?
Can I display this Splash Screen on button click?

Comment: That's good to know ..so what is the problem and or issue that you are faced with.. also please do a google search on what I have suggested initially as well as BackGroundWorker.. and show us what you have tried on your own.. nobody will code this for you..it's up to you to do more than just post a question here.. please read the link on how to ask a question as well.. good luck .

Comment: I Never told that I would like somebody code for me. I just ask a question if soneone could help.
If you don't want to help me, no problem, don't answer my question and have a good day!

Comment: what you are wanting to do is not very difficult once again do a google search on `BackgroudWorker and Splach Screen` cheers

Comment: Instead of a gif you can use standard progress bar and set IsIndeterminate="True".  This will allow you to style it accordingly.

Comment: First thing you should do is use a search engine to locate one of the many examples of how to do this that are all over the place. Next, try it out in a small prototype.  Then, if you have an issue, come here with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the following XAML, with one hidden `Image` and one `Button` that pretends to load data:

```
<StackPanel Margin="20">
    <Image
        x:Name="loadingGif"
        Height="30"
        Source="Assets/Square.bmp"
        Visibility="Hidden"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <Button
        Content="Load"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Click="OnGoClick" />
</StackPanel>
```

In the button's `Click` event handler, you make the `Image` visible and start a `BackgroundWorker`. Once the `BackgroundWorker` is done, hide the `Image`again:

```
private void OnGoClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    loadingGif.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += OnDoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += OnRunWorkerCompleted;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void OnDoWork(object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    Task.Delay(2000).Wait(); // Pretend to work
}

private void OnRunWorkerCompleted(object o, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    loadingGif.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

(You need to be careful about *where* you change the `Image.Visibility` property; this needs to happen on the UI thread.)

Comment: Thank You it's perfect !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the task for long running function(loading you data)

```
LoadGif();
await Task.Run(() => LoadYourData());
```